# Stack two pandas dataframes with different columns, keeping source dataframe as column, also

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a couple of toy dataframes I can stack using `df.append`, but I need to keep the source dataframes as a column, as well. I can't seem to find anything about how to do that. Here's what I do have:

```
d2005 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [2,4,5,6], "C": [3,5,7,8],
                     "G": [7,8,9,10]})
d2006 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,1,4,5], "B": [3,1,5,6], "D": ["a","c","d","e"],
                     "F": [7,8,10,12]})


    d2005

    A   B   C   G
0   1   2   3   7
1   2   4   5   8
2   3   5   7   9
3   4   6   8   10


d2006

    A   B   D   F
0   2   3   a   7
1   1   1   c   8
2   4   5   d   10
3   5   6   e   12
```

Then I can stack them like this:

```
d_combined = d2005.append(d2006, ignore_index = True, sort = True)

d_combined

    A   B   C    D     F       G
0   1   2   3.0     NaN     NaN     7.0
1   2   4   5.0     NaN     NaN     8.0
2   3   5   7.0     NaN     NaN     9.0
3   4   6   8.0     NaN     NaN     10.0
4   2   3   NaN     a   7.0     NaN
5   1   1   NaN     c   8.0     NaN
6   4   5   NaN     d   10.0    NaN
7   5   6   NaN     e   12.0    NaN
```

But what I really need is another column with the source dataframe added to the right end of `d_combined`. Something like this:

```
    A   B   C       D       G       F      From
0   1   2   3.0     NaN     7.0     NaN     d2005
1   2   4   5.0     NaN     8.0     NaN     d2005
2   3   5   7.0     NaN     9.0     NaN     d2005
3   4   6   8.0     NaN     10.0    NaN     d2005
4   2   3   NaN     a       NaN     7.0     d2006
5   1   1   NaN     c       NaN     8.0     d2006
6   4   5   NaN     d       NaN     10.0    d2006
7   5   6   NaN     e       NaN     12.0    d2006
```

Hopefully someone has a quick trick they can share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be simply achieved by adding the **From** column to the original dataframes itself.
So effectively,

```
d2005 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [2,4,5,6], "C": [3,5,7,8],
                 "G": [7,8,9,10]})
d2006 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,1,4,5], "B": [3,1,5,6], "D": ["a","c","d","e"],
                     "F": [7,8,10,12]})
```

Then,

```
d2005['From'] = 'd2005'
d2006['From'] = 'd2006'
```

And then you append,

```
d_combined = d2005.append(d2006, ignore_index = True, sort = True)
```

gives you something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This gets what you want but there should be a more elegant way:

```
df_list = [d2005, d2006]
name_list = ['2005', '2006']
for df, name in zip(df_list, name_list):
  df['from'] = name
```

Then

```
d_combined = d2005.append(d2006, ignore_index=True)
d_combined

    A   B   C       D      F        G       from
0   1   2   3.0     NaN     NaN     7.0     2005
1   2   4   5.0     NaN     NaN     8.0     2005
2   3   5   7.0     NaN     NaN     9.0     2005
3   4   6   8.0     NaN     NaN     10.0    2005
4   2   3   NaN     a       7.0     NaN     2006
5   1   1   NaN     c       8.0     NaN     2006
6   4   5   NaN     d       10.0    NaN     2006
7   5   6   NaN     e       12.0    NaN     2006
```

---

Alternatively, you can set `df.name` at the time of creation of the df and use it in the for loop.

```
d2005 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4], "B": [2,4,5,6], "C": [3,5,7,8],
                     "G": [7,8,9,10]} )
d2005.name = 2005
d2006 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [2,1,4,5], "B": [3,1,5,6], "D": ["a","c","d","e"],
                     "F": [7,8,10,12]})
d2006.name = 2006  



df_list = [d2005, d2006]
    for df in df_list:
      df['from'] = df.name
```